# Does someone know why font-weight: bold; wont work on mobile device?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Im trying to get bold text to work on the mobile device, its all fine on the pc but it dosent show on mobile device. I have embedded code from google fonts.

```css
.phone p {
 font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 line-height: 1.0; 
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Only the regular weight is loaded by default. To load regular and bold you would specify the weights in the URL: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap` or `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold&display=swap`. Your desktop browser is probably faking the bold effect since there is no bold version available.

Answer (score 0):

4 things.

1. - You only choose the normal font-weight on fonts.google.com - use the link Eder Gomez provided.
2. - Make a fallback like this **font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;**
3. - Instead of saying color:white, do a hex color instead like **color:#fff;**
4. - Instead of saying font-weight:bold, use the numbers for a more correct bold.

Roboto: font-weight:
400; = Regular
700; = Bold

Answer (score -1):

Only the regular weight is loaded by default. To load regular and bold you would specify the weights in the URL: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap or https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold&display=swap. Your desktop browser is probably faking the bold effect since there is no bold version available. – Turnip Apr 22 '20 at 10:12